# How can I build my own wireless charger for my cellphone?

Tags: wireless, charging, wireless-charging, mutual-inductance

I am designing a wireless charger for my cellphone, Where my Primary coil is energised with 1.5V and 0.3A, Where I have used a transistor to turn it on and off at a frequency of 1Mhz.
In the secondary coil I got a peak to peak voltage of 32V and Vavg of 0.8V, Which I later rectified using a resistor and capacitor in parallel and I achieved a Vavg of 5.8V and the current in Microamps.

Since the current was insufficient to charge my cellphone,How can i improve the current in secondary Coil.
Note: My primary coil had 40 turns
Secondary coil had 20 turns.

The distance between primary and secondary coil is less than 1cm

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0UPaw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Have you searched for possible similar questions on here - such as : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/352527/152903

Comment: @SolarMike I think this OP is likely interested in charging over short distances like already implemented in newer smart phones not the room wide power distribution.

Comment: So another similar question is : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139050/inductive-wireless-mobile-charger-circuit?rq=1

Comment: @Ariser as I pointed out similar questions - just need to search before posting... And this one : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141557/how-does-this-wireless-charger-work?rq=1

Comment: The wireless chargers you can buy are much more complex than this. What you have here is just the basic power transfer circuitry and it's incomplete as well because your phone needs DC and not 1 MHz AC like you have now. Also some **communication** happens between the charger and the phone. Without that the phone is unlikely to start charging (assuming you'd use the phone's build in charging coil). On Ebay you can buy wireless chargers for a few USD so why try to build something that is not going to work?

Comment: You couldn't even bother to spell "I" properly in the title, and again in the first word of the text!  That's where I stopped reading. Go away until you're ready to show some respect to the volunteers you are asking a favor from.

Comment: @OlinLathrop  Sorry for the mistake. I apologize

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  i wanted to build on my own. Wireless charger in ebay and amazon are costly.

Comment: *Wireless charger in ebay and amazon are costly* I see them for less than $ 5 on Ebay, from China, including shipping, how is that costly? And that one **will work**. Yours will not as I stated above. To make it work you will need more electronics, it will easily cost $ 5 as well. But sure, waste time and money on something that will never work.

Comment: @SolarMike That's right. Searching for similar question is a generic task to perform before posting own questions.

Answer (score 0):

The key for making this work is resonance. You need to make a primary resonant circuit (i.e. pure LC). Then you need to feed it AC at teh resonant frequency, not just any frequency. Third is you need a secondary resonant circuit that is tuned to the primary. Then it will work.

But beware, currents in both primary and secondary will be large. That's the whole point of making it resonant. You'll need to tune the frequency of the feeding power to be just off resonance (but close). Experiment and you'll lean a lot. These are only the basics.